# Upload file data and form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, html

I'm trying to pass my form data as well as data from a file being uploaded
However, I can only manage to pass the form data or file data but not both at the same time.

Here is my javascript for getting the data

```
var form = document.getElementById('AddDocs');
var data = new FormData(form);
var columns = [];
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    ParseFile(files[i]);
}
var propertyRows = document.getElementsByClassName("docPropertiesTable")(0).rows;
for (var i = 0; i < propertyRows.length - 1; i++) {
    //
    if (propertyRows(i).cells(1).children(0).value != "") {
        //if there is a value
        values.push(propertyRows(i).cells(1).children(0).value);
        data.append("value" + i, propertyRows(i).cells(1).children(0).value);
        //push the dataid of the column on to the array
        columns.push(propertyRows(i).cells(1).children(0).name.split("|")[0]);
        data.append("columns" + i, propertyRows(i).cells(1).children(0).name.split("|")[0]);

    }
}

var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ columns: columns, values:values, data:data });
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "EnterpriseUtilities.aspx/ProcessEnterpriseUpload",
    data: jsonText,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    failure: function () { alert("Uh oh"); }
});
```

Method 2 for uploading the file

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 && xhr.responseText) {
        alert("upload done!");
    } else {
        //alert("upload failed!");
    }
};
xhr.open('POST', "UploadFile.aspx");
xhr.send(data);
```

The ajax call is currently getting the form data and then the XMLHTTPRequest is getting the file. I need to make sure the file is uploaded first and then I need to take the data to insert into a database. How can I achieve the upload of the file without losing the form data?

EDIT:
I am trying to get upload the file via XMLHTTP or whatever means necessary. Then I need to get the metadata (form data) that the user enters. Both methods work independently.

My asp.net method for hadling the information is

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function ProcessEnterpriseUpload(columns() As String, values() As String, data As Object) As String
        //process information 
    End Function
```

I am mainly a desktop developer and am looking for guidance on where to go to get this working.

EDIT 2

Image for context.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDT9V.jpg

Drop file onto table. Fill in file information then when done I need to upload the actual file itself as well as any data the user fills in on the right hand side. There are more fields on the right, but for simplicity I included the top 2.

Comment: Why are you mixing `$.ajax` from jQuery with the low level XMLHttpRequest API? Why not stick consistently with one or the other? Also, why are you uploading `data` twice? Once as part of `jsonText` and once by itself?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Your post is confusing.  Does the form data post work by itself?  Does the file upload work by itself?  Are you just trying to figure out how to do the file upload first and then when that's complete do the data?

Comment: Are you trying to read content of the file and save it, or you are trying to upload the file and save metadata about it?

Comment: Yes both the ajax and XMLHTTPRequest work by themseleves. @RickS I am trying to upload the file and then the data when that's complete.

Comment: @mason I tried to append data to jsonText but it is empty when it is return ed on the server

Comment: Well, it is empty on the client? Do you inspect the HTTP Request to see if the data makes it into that? Where's your code on the server for handling the request? Your question is missing a lot of detail. You need to learn to trace this stuff through to identify the root of your problem.

Comment: @mason data is fine on the client. I am using asp.net and my method looks like this  <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function ProcessEnterpriseUpload(columns() As String, values() As String, data As object) As String

Comment: Do not post long code in comments. It needs to be in the question itself.

Comment: @wazz These are not answers, they are comments. I am using comments for their intended purpose, to gather more information. I am not providing constructive criticism at the moment, I am trying to gather more data and teach bme2010 the importance of learning to debug a program. If you believe you have enough information here to answer the question, then go ahead and feel free to do so.

Comment: you are doing it in a terrible way. i stand by what i said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I upload the file then if that succeeds send the meta data to be processed

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 && xhr.responseText) {
                 alert("upload done!");
                 var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ columns: columns, values:values});
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "EnterpriseUtilities.aspx/ProcessEnterpriseUpload",
                    data: jsonText,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    failure: function () { alert("Uh oh"); }
                });
            } else {
                //alert("upload failed!");
            }
        };
        xhr.open('POST', "UploadFile.aspx");
        xhr.send(data);
```